# Linux, keyboard: remap LNG to AltGr

Tags: linux, keyboard, key, mapping

I've got a keyboard with a cryptic LNG key next to the space bar, where AltGr usually sits. Is there a way to make AltGr (Alt) out of it?

This is `xev` console output for the LNG key being pressed and released once:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 56044552, (-281,525), root:(827,552),
    state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 56044568, (-281,525), root:(827,552),
    state 0x4, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 56044587, (-281,525), root:(827,552),
    state 0x5, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0xf5, subw 0x0, time 56044587, (-281,525), root:(827,552),
    state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Is there a way to put this info to use?

UPD:

Unfortunately, this is not possible, as the LNG key fires two key codes at once.

Remapping `Menu` to `Alt R`:

Change to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc:

```
key <MENU> {    [ Menu          ]   };
```

to

```
key <MENU> {    [ Alt_R         ]   };
```

Remove precompiled *.xkm files from /var/lib/xkb/, if any

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use xbindkeys. Install it, then run `xbindkeys --key` to see which keys are run. Then make your .xbindkeysrc file to bind that key. To my knowledge it triggers a command, so you can emulate the command using xdotool.

Heres a similar page with a xbindkeys tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/561464/896870

Xbindkeys and xdotool should be on the common repos.

Edit: I should also note that the xbindkeys daemon must be run at startup. Set up a startup command to simply run `xbindkeys` and it will start running. This cna be set up in Session and Startup for XFCE machine, but you could probably set it up in init.d too.

Comment: I want to remap a (modifier?) key. Do you mean binding it to a specific command? This does not look like what I want.

Comment: The modifier key can be changed by using xbindkeys. Associate the key with its keycode using xbindkeys --key (or -k) and a window will open; press the LNG key and it will provide you with the code. Then add this into your .xbindkeysrc file. The syntax is 

"xfce4-terminal"
m:0x10 + c:156

where this code launches the Terminal, for example. If you mean to map the key to another one, this probably wont help, but you could use it for anything else. Xdotool is great for macros also.